# Parsing Json in Json

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm working in a Jenkinsfile and trying to parse the following return output.  I can get the uuid but I can't get `name`.  Looking for some guidance.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
    node('ansible'){
      stage('Get VM List'){
        def content = sh (returnStdout: true, script: "curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/octet-stream' 'http://someurlapi'").trim()
        def vmList = readJSON text: content;

        //Works
        echo vmList[0].uuid
}}
```

**Return Output**

```
[
  {
    "num": XX,
    "ip": "XX.XX.XX.XX",
    "type": "KVM",
    "name": "machinename",
    "state": "Running",
    "ram": 4096,
    "ram-display": "4 GiB",
    "zpool": {
      "name": "zpool",
      "compression": "lz4",
      "mountpoint": "\/mnt",
      "mounted": true
    },
    "uuid": "d7622bd3-ed3d-5000-ae01-89ab294933r1",
    "autostart": false,
    "cpu": 2
  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out  I changed it to

`echo vmList[0]["name"]`